# Check if a program exists from a Fish script

Tags: shell, fish

How can I check if a program exists within a fish script?

I know that there is no absolute solution with Bash, but using `if type PROGRAM >/dev/null 2>&1; then...` gave good results.

Is there something similar with fish?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There is `type -q`, as in

```
if type -q $program
     # do stuff
end
```

which returns 0 if something is a function, builtin or external program (i.e. if it is something fish will execute).

There is also

- `command -q`, which will return 0 only if it exists as an external program
- `builtin -q`, which will return 0 only if it is a fish builtin
- `functions -q`, which will return 0 only if it is a fish function

For all of these the "-q" flag silences all output and just queries for existence.

If e.g. `builtin -q` returns true, that just means it is *also* a builtin - it can still be a function or command as well.

`command -q` works since fish 3.1.0 because the `-q` flag implies `-s`, before it would have to be `command -sq`.

Comment: Hiya faho, is this the correct way to check multiple executables in path: `if type -q tldr; and type -q peco; tldr $argv | peco; end;` Or is there a better way? Maybe to do it all in one go e.g. `type -q tldr peco` (the docs do say we can specify multiple names for `type` but it does not fail when I try it that it returns true e.g. `type -q aaa bbb; and echo true` it doesn't print anything as expected but `if type -q aaa bbb; echo true; end` does print `true`. So what's up?

Comment: `type -q` returns true when *at least one* of the arguments exists - `type -q type slartibartfast` will succeed everywhere because `type` always exists. So yes, you will have to check separately.